# running commands within a Docker user defined network

Tags: docker, networking

After creating the next network using docker:

```
 sudo docker network create --driver bridge mynet_nw
```

how can I do to issue commands from inside this network? i.e it is like simulating my machine is inside mynet_nw so I can issue ping commands to different docker images created inside mynet_nw?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue commands from any Docker container inside your network. You just need to add a container first. See [`docker network connect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/) for that.

Either way, any Docker container on a network can talk to any other Docker container on the same network. Assuming you have your host, `containerA`, and `containerB`, you'll be able to ping any of those three from each other:

```
containerA:~$ ping 172.18.0.1 # from containerA to host
56 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
56 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.098 ms
56 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
56 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms

containerA:~$ ping 172.18.0.3 # from containerA to containerB
56 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
56 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
56 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms
56 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
```

Asssuming you know hostnames, you *should* be able to even ping with hostnames directly. This might be a bit weirder when attempting to ping your host, but it should work between containers.

```
containerA:~$ ping containerB # from containerA to containerB
56 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
56 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
56 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
56 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.0811 ms
```

Comment: could I run
containerA:~$ ping containerB # from containerA to containerB
o avoid using the ip addreeses

Comment: Assuming hostnames are set up, you should be able to run direct pings. I prefer to use IP addresses, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I suggest to read the documentation for the docker network commands: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/#related-commands
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/

Anyway the docker network generates a network and you need a container to execute commands in there.

Example:

```
docker run -it alpine --network mynet_nw /bin/bash
ping mydb
```

You can alway check the network from the host itself if you know the name of the container:

```
INSTANCE_NAME='myalpine'
IPADD=$( docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $INSTANCE_NAME )
ping $IPADD
```